# PHP login cookie is not being set on clients computer (in Chrome, Firefox and IE) but works everywhere else. Client cannot log in

Tags: php, cookies, authentication

Is there anything wrong with my cookie code?  Has anyone else experienced a similar issue?

I have trawled stackoverflow and the rest of the net looking for a solution, without success.

My code works just fine when tested on multiple browsers on multiple computers. Everywhere but the client's browser! She's running windows 7 and has tried logging in with Chrome, Firefox and IE. She has tried clearing cookies. I even suggested she disable Avast antivirus in case it was rejecting the secure connection for some reason. Can't for the life of me work out what could possibly be wrong with my code.

Browser connection is via SSL (https) using a comodo certificate. Pages reliant on login are in multiple directories across the domain (root, /admin, /admin/includes/). Site is on a live apache server running PHP version 5.3.28.

Write code:
    $securityTimeout = time()+7200;
    $cookieDomain = "www.mysite.info";
    //setcookie(name, value, expire, path, domain, secure, httponly);
    setcookie ("loggedin", "true", $securityTimeout, "/", "$cookieDomain",true,true);

Read code:

```
if ((isset($_COOKIE["loggedin"]))&&($_COOKIE["loggedin"]=="true"))
{display fetched document}
else{
redirect to login
}
```

Client's browser is either not setting the cookies, or is setting then forgetting.  She is being immediately bounced back to the login page. Unfortunately I do not have access to the clients computer to run localised tests.

Can anyone see a problem with my code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Change up some variables. Ask her to try using a different computer at her site - if that also fails, then maybe her site's firewall is stripping cookie headers. Or if she has a laptop, ask her to try using it from home, outside her site's network.

Ask her to try logging in with a different account that you know works, and you should also try logging in from your site with her account, just in case it's something specific to her account.

If you want to get more technical with her, ask her (or her IT folks) to install "Edit This Cookie" on Chrome (or a similar extension on another browser) to see the cookies and make sure you know exactly what's being sent, and that the cookie isn't being deleted. Also use an inspector like Firebug to look at the data being sent with the request and make sure the cookie is part of that data.

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestions Brian.  I have tried everything you mentioned except her attempting to log in from outside her work network.  I shall ask her to give it a go.

Comment: The question, in a nutshell, is: is the problem specific to her computer, to her site, or to her account? Change one of these at a time and see what happens.